# SAML2-SLO using Spring Security 6 does not send request to SAML server

Tags: spring-security

I configured SAML2 registrations according to the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/saml2/index.html) and got SAML2 login working. Unfortunately I could not figure out how to get the [logout](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/saml2/logout.html) working. When sending a POST to /logout, the user is logged out of the system itself, but not logged out at the AP. There is no saml2:LogoutRequest sent to the AP and the SAML session attributes are not cleared.

Debugging shows, `Saml2LogoutRequestFilter` is not used first-hand, since the endpoints do not match and - of course - the user does not send a saml2:LogoutRequest object; so this is expected. `Saml2LogoutResponseFilter` also is not utilized, since this whould only be used processing logout answers from the AP.

What *is* utilized, is the `LogoutFilter`. What I unserstood reading the docs was, this would first log out the user from the system itself (which is fine), and *afterward* send a saml2:LogoutRequest to the AP, which is never done.

The configuration reads as:

```yaml
spring:
  security:
    saml2:
      relyingparty:
        registration:
          saml:
            acs:
              binding: POST
              location: "{baseUrl}/sso/{registrationId}/response"
            assertingparty:
              entity-id: "http://localhost:8000/saml2/idp/metadata.php"
              metadata-uri: "http://localhost:8000/saml2/idp/metadata.php"
              singlesignon:
                url: "http://localhost:8000/saml2/idp/SSOService.php"
                sign-request: false
              singlelogout:
                url: "http://localhost:8000/saml2/idp/SingleLogoutService.php"
                binding: REDIRECT
            entity-id: "localhost"
            singlelogout:
              url: "{baseUrl}/sso/logout/saml"
              binding: POST
              response-url: "{baseUrl}/sso/logout/saml"
```

and the filter config looks like that:

```kotlin
    @Bean
    fun filterChain(http: HttpSecurity/*, registrations: RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository*/): SecurityFilterChain {
        ...
        // saml login
        http.saml2Login { saml2LoginConfigurer ->
            saml2LoginConfigurer
                .authenticationRequestUri("/sso/{registrationId}/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl(samlResponseUrl.replace("{baseUrl}", ""))
                .authenticationManager(ProviderManager(samlAuthenticationProvider()))
                .defaultSuccessUrl(samlRedirectUrl)
                .failureUrl(samlRedirectUrlNewUser)
        }
        // saml (sso) logout
        http.saml2Logout { saml2LogoutConfigurer ->
            saml2LogoutConfigurer
                .logoutRequest { request -> request.logoutUrl("/sso/logout/saml") }
                .logoutResponse { response -> response.logoutUrl("/sso/logout/saml") }
        }
```

Comment: If you debug the `LogoutFilter` what is the configured `logoutSuccessHandler`? It should be an instance of `Saml2RelyingPartyInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler`

Comment: I'll have a closer look on Monday. Thanks!

Comment: A bit later, but anyway: The main culprit here was not using a subclass of `Saml2Authentication` in the login resolver. Subclasing it resolved the issue. Now I need to figure out how to get the [logout customization](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/saml2/logout.html#_customizing_saml2logoutrequest_resolution) to work.